# How to get top/left position and height of the in-line element on the screen?

Tags: javascript

is there a way to get an accurate top/left position using pure JavaScript (without third-party libraries) of the in-line element on a given page? This is super easy for block elements or elements that have a fixed/relative positioning.

Second part of the question is regarding getting accurate height of such in-line element. Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, the following function (courtesy of [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)) achieves what you're looking for:

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;

    if(obj.offsetParent) 
    {
        do 
        {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } 
        while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }

    return [curleft,curtop];
}
```

I have put together a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HN2Dr/) showing the retrieval of an inline element's position.